# Refer to "class" object in object function inside a "class"

Tags: javascript

Is there a way I can refer to the class object, in the image.onload?
`this` refers to the image itself. How I can refer to the Texture object?

https://jsfiddle.net/yL648t40/

```
function Texture(url){
  this.image = new Image();
  this.image.src = url;
  this.image.onload = function(){
    this.width = this.image.width;
    this.height = this.image.height;
  }
}

text = new Texture("http://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/styles/watermarked/public/bone2-equus_hemionus.png");

document.body.innerHTML += text.image + "<br>";
document.body.innerHTML += text.image.src + "<br>";
document.body.innerHTML += text.image.width + "<br>";
```

I've tried using something like this inside the Texture class

```
self = this;
this.image.onload = function(self){
    self.width = self.image.width;
    self.height = self.image.height;
}
```

But obiviously it doesn't work

Comment: `self` works when you declare it properly as `var self = …` and remove it from the parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the self argument from your handler:

```
self = this;
this.image.onload = function(){ 
  self.width = self.image.width;     
   self.height = self.image.height;
}
```

Another option would be to bind the function to this, but that's complicated using pure javascript.

Comment: Oh, didn't know I could use a class argument without `this` into an object function. Thank you

Comment: For the sake of completeness: it is not a class, and it's more about references and scope, if you want to research about the basics...

Comment: A global `self` variable does work.

Answer (score 0):

You have sevaral options.

**First**: Use the `self` workaround as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39475147/1323504).

**Second**: Use `Function.bind` like this.

```
function Texture(url){
  this.image = new Image();
  this.image.src = url;

  var loadHandler = function(){
    this.width = this.image.width;
    this.height = this.image.height;
  };

  this.image.onload = loadHandler.bind(this);
}
```

**Third:** Use ES6 arrow functions, which will preserve the `this` context in their bodies (if your environment can afford ES6). [Here](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2015/11/02/of-classes-and-arrow-functions-a-cautionary-tale/) is a good article.

Comment: Didn't know about `Function.bind`, I'll take a look into it. 
What you think is better? `self` workaround or `Function.bind`?